# Collapse bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть страничка с двумя элементами. Сейчас это работает так: при нажатии на слово `About` или `Projects` выводится текст. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на `About` при нажатии на `Projects` скрывался обратно текст `About` и открывался `Projects`.Другими словами,нужно, чтобы при открытии одного блока другие сворачивались.Попробовал эти два блока засунуть в один контейнер и к каждому блоку добавил атрибут data-parent, но, это почему-то не работает.

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="daughter">
         <div class="container" data-toggle="collapse" href="#About" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="About" data-target="#About">
            About
         </div>
         <div class="collapse" id="About">
            <div class="well">
               ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="daughter">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="container" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Projects" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="About" data-target="#Projects">
                Projects
            </div>
            <div class="collapse" id="Projects">
                <div class="well">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Простыми средствами `bootstrap` закрыть "чужой" объект не получится. Нужен будет JS

Comment: @cyadvert Не подскажите как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код не универсальный. Конкретно под Вашу задачу.

```
$('[data-target=#Projects]').bind('click', function() {  // событие будет запускаться при нажатии на кнопку с [data-target=#Projects]
    if ($('#About').attr('aria-expanded')=='true') { // проверяем, открыт ли #About
        $('[data-target=#About]').trigger('click'); // если открыт - "наджимаем" на его кнопку, что его закроет
    }
});
$('[data-target=#About]').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#Projects').attr('aria-expanded')=='true') {
        $('[data-target=#Projects]').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Оба элемента практически эдентичны. Меняются только ID элементов с которыми работаем.
Итак, обоим элементам `[data-target=#About]` и `[data-target=#Projects]` присваевается функция, которая будет запущена при клике на элемент.
Функция проверяет, открыт ли второй элемент: `($('#Projects').attr('aria-expanded')=='true')`, и если открыт "запускает" нажатие на кнопку второго элемента, что его закроет.